# Object “Grouping” - delete children with parent

Tags: parent, collections

I'm writing a Blender (2.81) Python Addon which needs to display one mesh in the Viewport (low res) and one for Rendering (high res) (these are plants/trees). I currently create two objects and use the low-res object as the parent of the high-res object. While this is configurable, by default the high-res object is not visible in the viewport and is not selectable. This presents the low-res object to user in the viewport where they can move, rotate, and scale it and have those changes affect the high-res child at render time (and the user doesn't have to think about the high-res object at all).

The challenge I currently have is deleting the parent in the viewport leaves the child in the scene, where I would expect to be able to delete “the tree” by clicking on it in the viewport and pressing X.

Am I thinking about object composition the right way here, or is my brain still stuck in SketchUp land and I need to adjust to think in Blender terms?

Is the Parent/Child mechanism the right approach for this kind of composing?

Should I be using a custom collection to contain the two objects instead? (still can’t delete with X in the 3D viewport).

For example, in the image below the viewport looks like the upper-left by default. It can be configured to show the high-res in the viewport as in the lower-left, but only the low-res is selectable (in wireframe if the high-res is visible). Either way, only the high-res is rendered as in the lower right:
[image]

Comment: Yes, blender delete object does not remove children.  IMO looks like a job for collections. Present the user with a collection instance (collection has hi and lo res mesh, no parenting).

Comment: Thanks for the response @batFINGER. I mocked this up in the UI to experiment. To delete a tree from the scene I would need to identify it in the outliner, most easily done by clicking on the desired tree in the scene, then find the active object in the outliner, right click the containing collection, and select "Delete Hierarchy". That seems pretty cumbersome - especially in a scene with lots of plants. Is that the typical workflow - or have a missed something that makes this easier?

Comment: My other concern is that users will attempt to delete the low-res object in the viewport and not realize the high-res object remains (since it isn't visible in the viewport). I think I must still be confused about how people build scenes with multiple complex objects.

Comment: Please check out instancing collections. Add both to a collection. Add object > collection instance > choose the collection.   The instanced object contains all objects of the collection and can be deleted in one fell swoop.

Comment: That seems to be precisely what I was looking for. Thank you @batFINGER!